# I have a load of data on Google Sheets. I would to use this to practice running SQL queries. How can I do this?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have decided to learn SQL as I am running into limitations on excel.

I have a bunch of data on sheets/excel which would be perfect for me to practice using SQL. Unfortunately, whilst I have spent a lot of time learning how to run queries I know little about how to starting using SQL in the first place.

So my question is, how do I go from having my data in xls to querying a database?

At this point it's not huge amounts of data and its just for private use; preferably this would be doable on ChromeOS (or, if not, on Mac OS X) and for free.

This is what I think I will need to do, am I on the right track or is there a simpler way to achieve what I want?

- convert the xls file to csv
- convert the csv files to sql using an online converter
- signup for a free trial of (eg) google cloud services
- create an SQL instance
- connect to the SQL instance using a mysql client
- import the sql files into the SQL instance

Answer (score 0):

Convert your Google Sheets to excel. Then follow the instructions on MySQL docs to import your excel data into a MySQL table. You can find the instructions here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-for-excel/en/mysql-for-excel-export.html